# postgresql multi join syntax

Tags: postgresql, left-join

```
SELECT sessions_compare.*
    FROM archive_sessions as f_session, sessions_compare
    LEFT JOIN archive_sessions as s_session ON (s_session.id = sessions_compare.second_session_id)
    LEFT JOIN consols as f_consol ON (f_session.console_id = f_consol.id)

    where sessions_compare.first_session_id = f_session.id
```

after executing a get error like

> ERROR:  invalid reference to FROM-clause entry for table "f_session"
>   LINE 13:
>   LEFT JOIN consols as f_consol ON (f_session.console_id
>   =...
>
> HINT:  There is an entry for table "f_session", but it cannot be referenced from this
>   part of the query.

When i switch places and have `from` like `sessions_compare, archive_sessions as f_session`
i get error like

> ERROR:  invalid reference to FROM-clause entry for table
>   "sessions_compare" 
>   LINE 4: ... archive_sessions as s_session ON
>   (s_session.id = sessions_c...
>
> HINT:  There is an entry for table "sessions_compare", but it cannot be
>   referenced from this part of the query.

And only thing that work is

```
SELECT sessions_compare.*
    FROM sessions_compare
    LEFT JOIN archive_sessions as s_session ON (s_session.id = sessions_compare.second_session_id)

    ,archive_sessions as f_session

    LEFT JOIN consols as f_consol ON (f_session.console_id = f_consol.id)
    where sessions_compare.first_session_id = f_session.id
```

And my question is it normal ?? Im young in Postgresql in mysql when using multiple join from tables needed to be in `()`

Comment: Using shorter correlation name tags for the table entries would probaby simplify reading.

Comment: BTW: when you edit your question, it is adviasble not to remove fragments of it on which people can have reacted. I spent some time repairing the silly query, and all that you did is remove it from the question.

Comment: Its not about the query, its about syntax. I make this query work, I was wounder if its normal to create query this way

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38750599/sql-joins-there-is-an-entry-for-table-but-it-cannot-be-referenced

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that's documented behavior in PostgreSQL.

> [In any case JOIN binds more tightly than the commas separating FROM items.](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-select.html)

That means PostgreSQL acts like it builds its working table by evaluating the JOIN clauses before evaluating a comma-list in the FROM clause.

Best practice is generally considered to be to always use JOIN clauses; never put more than one table name in the FROM clause.

Answer (score 2):

Changing the main query to a JOIN (and adding/shortening some correlation names) seems to fix the problem.

```
DROP SCHEMA fuzz CASCADE;
CREATE SCHEMA fuzz;
SET search_path='fuzz';

create table archive_sessions ( id INTEGER NOT NULL
 , console_id INTEGER NOT NULL, game_id INTEGER NOT NULL);
create table sessions_compare (first_session_id INTEGER NOT NULL
 , second_session_id INTEGER NOT NULL);
create table consols (id INTEGER NOT NULL);
create table games (id INTEGER NOT NULL);
create table localizations ( consols_id INTEGER NOT NULL, bars_id INTEGER NOT NULL);
create table bars ( id_bars INTEGER NOT NULL, area_id INTEGER NOT NULL);
create table areas ( id_areas INTEGER NOT NULL );

SELECT sco.*
    FROM archive_sessions as ase
    JOIN sessions_compare sco ON sco.first_session_id = ase.id

    LEFT JOIN archive_sessions as ss ON (ss.id = sco.second_session_id)
    LEFT JOIN consols as sc ON (ss.console_id = sc.id)
    LEFT JOIN games as sg ON (ss.game_id = sg.id)
    LEFT JOIN localizations as sl ON (sc.id = sl.consols_id)
    LEFT JOIN bars as sb ON (sl.bars_id = sb.id_bars)
    LEFT JOIN areas as sa ON (sb.area_id = sa.id_areas)



    LEFT JOIN consols as fc ON (ase.console_id = fc.id)
    LEFT JOIN games as fg ON (ase.game_id = fg.id)
    LEFT JOIN localizations as fl ON (fc.id = fl.consols_id)
    LEFT JOIN bars as fb ON (fl.bars_id = fb.id_bars)
    LEFT JOIN areas as fa ON (fb.area_id = fa.id_areas)

    -- WHERE sco.first_session_id = ase.id
        ;
```

Comment: But I dont want to change this query, I want it to stay like I showed it

Comment: The only thing I did (except for some renaming) was replacing the `FROM x, y` by the equivalent `FROM x JOIN y` construct, and putting the WHERE clause into the ON condition. (and that is exactly what @Catcall suggests, BTW)