# SQL joins, "there is an entry for table but it cannot be referenced"

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis

I have a SQL query which is failing, giving me the error:

> "There is an entry for table but it cannot be referenced from this part of the query"

Going through the query, I need both all 3 tables, but only trips and boats have a matching ID to join on. Test is a shapefile which I need to perform a postGIS function on but it shares no similar column id's to the other two.

```
 select trips.*
 from trips, test
 inner join boats on boats.id = trips.boat_id
 where st_intersects(trips.geom, test.geom) and
 boats.uid = 44
```

I think it has something to do with the join statement but I don't really understand what. I'd be very interested in an explanation of what is happening here.

Comment: To clarify - are you intentionally trying to cross-join `trips` and `test`?

Comment: don't mix implicit and explicit joins and never put commas into the `from` clause.

Comment: In more traditional way it could be `... from trips join test on (st_intersects(trips.geom, test.geom)) join boats on (boats.id = trips.boat_id) where boats.uid = 44;`

Comment: @Abelisto, that worked thanks. Can you explain why?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Simple rule:  *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use explicit `JOIN` syntax . . . even if that means writing out `CROSS JOIN`.

As mentioned in the comments, the right way to write the query is:

```
 select trips.*
 from trips inner join
      test
      on st_intersects(trips.geom, test.geom) inner join
      boats
      on boats.id = trips.boat_id
 where boats.uid = 44;
```

However, the question is why this doesn't work:

```
from trips,
     test inner join
     boats
     on boats.id = trips.boat_id
```

First, I want to note that the failure of this syntax is better described in the MySQL [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html) than in the Postgres documentation:

> However, the precedence of the comma operator is less than of INNER
>   JOIN, CROSS JOIN, LEFT JOIN, and so on. If you mix comma joins with
>   the other join types when there is a join condition, an error of the
>   form Unknown column 'col_name' in 'on clause' may occur. Information
>   about dealing with this problem is given later in this section.

I think a simpler way of describing this is that `JOIN` is an operator that acts on the tables/expressions that are its arguments.  The comma separates the arguments.  So, the first table simply isn't recognized because the comma "blocks" it.

I think you can get around this using parentheses:

```
from (trips, test inner) join
     boats
     on boats.id = trips.boat_id
```

You can definitely get around it using `CROSS JOIN`:

```
from trips cross join
     test inner join
     boats
     on boats.id = trips.boat_id
```

But why bother?  There is a correct way to write the query.

Comment: It looks like the 'right way' as mentioned here relies on the join being a boolean value. Just FYI for any others out there.