# There is an entry for table "a", but it cannot be referenced from this part of the query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I wrote a query which will generate sub periods from an existant periods in a table named `allotment`:

```
select a.product_id, 
daterange((lower(a.allotment_period) + concat(n.i - 1, ' days')::interval)::date, 
(upper(a.allotment_period) + concat(n.i, ' days')::interval)::date, '[]') 
from test.allotment as a
cross join(select * from generate_series(1, a.period_length)) as n(i)
where a.id = 2
```

I got this error:

```
ERROR: invalid reference to FROM-clause entry for table "a" LINE 5: cross `join(select * from generate_series(1, a.period_length)... ^ HINT: There is an entry for table "a", but it cannot be referenced from this part of the query. SQL state: 42P01 Character: 250`
```

I found a similar question [SQL joins, “there is an entry for table but it cannot be referenced”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38750599/sql-joins-there-is-an-entry-for-table-but-it-cannot-be-referenced?rq=1) but it doesnt resolve my problem. Any one has a solution for this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in the `from` clause.  In more recent versions of Postgres, you can use:

```
from test.allotment a cross join lateral
     generate_series(1, a.period_length) n(i)
```

In older versions, you can include the `generate_series()` in the `select`:

```
from (select a.*, generate_series(1, a.period_length) as i
      from test.allotment a
     ) a
```